# editButtonItem Not Showing Up

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

**The Problem:**
The built-in editButtonItem that Xcode automatically comments out when a new UITableViewController class is created does not work when I delete the comment slashes (`//`).  By does not work I mean that the edit button does not appear at all. Swiping a cell does not work either.

**Attempted Solutions:**
I have tried to follow the various workarounds that have been posted on other stackoverflow threads to no avail. Most of the posts that I have found talk about various aspects of the edit button not working (e.g., no minus signs showing up, etc…) but very few that I have found in which the edit button does not show up at all.

**Hunch:**
I have a hunch that it might have something to do with the UITableViewController not being properly implemented. I am very new to object-oriented programming as well as objective-c, so I apologize if the answer is something very basic—but hey, it's part of the learning process. Any help is much appreciated.

**Code:**

***_*__*_*.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "IndividualRecipeViewController.h"

@class BrowsePrivateRecipeViewController;

@protocol BrowsePrivateRecipeViewControllerDelegate
- (void)browsePrivateRecipeViewControllerDidFinish:(BrowsePrivateRecipeViewController *)controller;
@end

@interface BrowsePrivateRecipeViewController : UITableViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) id <BrowsePrivateRecipeViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSUInteger listLength;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *dictionaryOfRecipes;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *arrayOfRecipeNames;

// ... methods

@end
```

***_*__*_*.m**

```
@interface BrowsePrivateRecipeViewController ()

@end

@implementation BrowsePrivateRecipeViewController

@synthesize delegate = _delegate;
@synthesize listLength = _listLength;
@synthesize dictionaryOfRecipes = _dictionaryOfRecipes;
@synthesize arrayOfRecipeNames = _arrayOfRecipeNames;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // ... code here

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

// ... other methods
```

**UPDATE:**

**[LINK TO SOURCE CODE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/k4v5oaiy11rxism/project3.zip)**

So I have decided to post the source code to my whole project. I am having this problem with multiple files, but if I get it fixed in one, I am pretty sure that the rest will fall into place.

Please focus on the files `BrowsePrivateRecipeViewController.m/.h.` This is the most straightforward instance of the problem.

Once again thank you for your patience and help.

Sincerely,
Jason

Comment: Take a look at my answer. CodaFi is right but it would have been nice if he showed you some code to fix it. I've included some simple code to get you started.

Comment: I would assume that he knows how to make a UIBarButtonItem, but I do like a little push in the right direction every so often for the OP.  +1

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I would definately not use a custom button for editing the table. It's unnecessary simply because there's already one built in.

Just use `UIViewController`s `editButtonItem`.
If you have to perform additional stuff on button press, override `-setEditing:animated:` and call `super` first.

The error you mentioned above is caused because you're trying to access the `navigationBar`s `navigationItem`, which does not exist. You should access your view controller's `navigationItem`.

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
```

Comment: That is what I tried to do initially (see original post as per my edits). For some reason it is still not working. I think I am just going to rebuild the entire `UITableViewController` from scratch and see if I didn't just accidentally edit something that I should have left untouched.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make a button first. This will make an Edit button then add it to the rightBarButtonItem spot.

```
// Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
UIBarButtonItem *editButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit target:self action:@selector(editTable)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButton;
```

You then need to set up a method to turn on the table's edit mode.

```
- (void)editTable
{
    [self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
}
```

**Update:**

Just read your question again and noticed you want swipe to delete as well. You need to added these methods in order to add that to your tableview.

```
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}


// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}
```

**Update 2**

__.h

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationBar *navigationBar;
```

__.m

```
@synthesize navigationBar;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    //...

    UIBarButtonItem *editButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit target:self action:@selector(editTable)];
    self.navigationBar.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButton;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply, but the button is still not showing up after following your first two code suggestions above. I will update my original post to show you how the code currently looks.

Comment: Throw in a screenshot of your app while you're at it so we can see what we're working with.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have less than 10 reputation points, so I was unable to post a screenshot.

Comment: Does your tableView have a navigation bar at the top? and if so how a was it added?

Comment: Work around. Here are some imgur hosted screenshots of the app. Xcode screenshot: [link](http://i.imgur.com/a6WcN.png). In app screenshot: [link](http://i.imgur.com/Atjad.png).

Comment: Alright you probably need to hook up your NavigationBar and add it directly. Add an IBOutlet for the UINavigationBar. then instead of self.navigationItem make it self.**navigationBarName**.navigationitem.rightBarButtonItem I'll edit my answer with more details if this doesn't do it for you.

Comment: Still no dice. I am assuming that the **navigationBarName** is, as per your updated answer above, be "navigationBar." I hooked up navigationBar with the navigation bar in the .xib file. On the line `self.navigationBar.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButton` I get the error: `Property navigationItem not found on object of type 'UINavigationBar *'`

Answer (score 1):

You aren't `alloc`'ing or `init`'ing the editButtonItem object, so how can you expect to retain it (equals sign), let alone have it show up?  You're basically sending a message to nil.